# jquery blockUI inoked by MVC3 controller's action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action, blockui

Do you think, is there a way to make a blockUI message to appear in some way after MVC3 controller's action has been invoked, not by AJAX, but by pressing a submit button in the form and executing the form's submit action?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a field in the model which is set accordingly, and then in the document.ready where the popups are invoked when the model's value change, it shows/don't show the popup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want blockUI to be active during the whole form submission.  If you are talking about a basic form post, I don't think that there is a way for blockUI to be active the entire time.

You're making a request for two separate pages.  Even if you initialise blockUI on the load of the form post, there will still be a point where blockUI will not be active ( transitioning from the form page to the form post ).

If your intent is to have blockUI open the whole time between "button press" and "result", you may wish to consider submitting your form via AJAX.